# Perl, Unix, & Ksh - Monitoring cron's history & future

Tags: unix, cron, ksh

Is there a way to monitor enqueued cron commands?

I want to be able to view a report of cron jobs that have not yet run, but are scheduled to run for the rest of the day.

Also, is there a way to view cron's history?

I want to be able to view a report of cron jobs that have already run for the day.

My main goal is to write a script that can double-check that a future cron job has actually been executed successfully by comparing the enqueued jobs for the day against the completed jobs for the day.

I'm not too familiar with cron, so maybe these usage statistics already exist somewhere? Whatever the case, I cannot find the answers to my above questions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The cron daemon works by examining all users' crontab files every minute and deciding which jobs should be started. There is no "queue" of jobs for the day being managed.

Comment: @mob - thanks for the info... can you tap into that process and fork stuff from it?

Comment: I doubt it. Cron may or may not syslog its activities. I suppose you could something like Perl's [`Schedule::Cron`](http;//search.cpan.org/perldoc?Schedule::Cron) module as a cron emulator and see what jobs it would run. You also might have better luck asking this question on serverfault.com.

Comment: @mob - was wondering whether or not to ask it there too... thanks for the help, im closing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no queue, but the crontabs will tell you when crons will be run.

For tracking crons that have run in the past, there is a log that has this info. On Red Hat, it's located at /var/log/cron.log

Comment: @Cheese: then you're not using RedHat. Check your documentation to see where crontabs are stored for your distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Cron does not use a queue exactly (but `at` does).

The following Perl module does what is asked for future events (and guesses past events): [`Schedule::Cron::Events`](https://metacpan.org/release/Schedule-Cron-Events)

For true history, some versions of `cron` can log with `syslog`, or log to `/var/log/cron.log`, `/var/log/cron`, `/var/cron/log`, or `/var/cron/olog`

Also see the `man` pages:

- Linux: [`cron(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron)
- Solaris: [`cron(1M)`](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/cron.1.html)